# Linkedin with OAuth2 ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, linkedin-api

I am developing an Iphone app in which i want to integrate it with linkedIn.
I want user info in my app and i want to do it with oAuth 2.0.
I tried to integration with oAuth 1.0, but i am having problems in callback.

is there any sample or good tutorial available for linkedIn integration in iphone using oAuth 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For personal usage & help others which want a sample app for **LinkedIn** using **OAuth 2.0** protocol, I wrote a client using [OAuth2Client](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client) which is on GitHub:

https://github.com/bouzikas/LinkedinOauth2

Comment: I won't be able to test this for some time. If other people can acknowledge that this works then i can accept your answer.

Comment: @dimimpou 
i run your code.  i am unable to call back to the app once i login success.

Comment: There would be an error somewhere in the retrieving process. You are not giving too much information on where exactly is your problem. Where do you think the process is stacked? getting the authorization code or access_token?

Comment: @dimimpou

app open in broswer and success fully logged in.
After that it needs to be redirect url (linkedin accepts only http: urls).
It wont back to app.

Comment: Yes you have to add a redirect url in your end and accept the result for verification. After that you can redirect back to your app <title>code=<?php echo $authCode;?></title><script type="text/javascript">location.href="your_app_scheme://"</script> and the app will automatically parse the title and get the authorization code. See app scheme if you don't know how to set it.

Comment: However this example has an embedded webview so you don't have do an app scheme.

Answer (score 1):

There is easy and good tutorial on github.com ,[Here](https://github.com/Himanshulanjewar/LinkedinIntegrationToiOS)

Note:
Make sure to integrate all the classes of Crypto folder

It will work for sure

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.i have used this library before, in this project everything works. But  when i created new project with this library, then problem arises in call back.do i need to change anything after creating new project?

Comment: i dont understand what's this in initLinkedInApi fuction in oAuthLoginView.m .  linkedInCallbackURL = @"hdlinked://linkedin/oauth";

Comment: I am not getting your problem, would you please post your console output if possible?

Comment: it's opening login page of linkedin, but after logging in it should come back to our app. but it's not coming back.

Comment: I tried with same github example,and its work in my application,so make sure again step by step using Logging

Comment: do i need to create customURL for an app or set callbackURL in app settings on developer.linkedIn.com ? Because i haven't done any of these.

Comment: yes,then you have to set callback URl first, In call you can write any URL like www,abc.com but it should ve valid URL

Comment: I created customURL in which i am giving "com.mycompany.app" as URL identifier and in URL scheme i am writing "app". and i am changing linkedInCallbackURL to "app://com.mycompany.app" and also tried this "com.mycompany.app" way. I am guessing i just have to set it in code, not in app settings. right?

Comment: If you have some time then can u help more to solve my problem ? i can send my test project to you..

Comment: yaa sure, you upload rpoject on github and comment your link to me

Comment: one thing i forgot to tell you is that it works when i specify website url. can i send it by an email?

Comment: No, I will not able to get your code via email because of some restriction, so its better to use github way

Comment: will it be ok if i don't give you api key and secret key?

Comment: ya no prob..i will use mine

Comment: created temp project here.  https://github.com/BThakrar/LoginLinkedIn Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: for now i specified callback url to google.com from app settings,and it works. If you need to set it to anything else then let me know.

Comment: did u get what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

This link provides a good starting point for using iOS - LinkedIn with or without a backend server with oauth2:

https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI

Comment: Do you have working demo of it to retrieve user's email address ?

Comment: A working demo can be found on Readme of this library IOSLinkedInAPI, but LinkedIn API does not support email field. See this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/3265) for further information.

Comment: Thanks for update and a quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

check for the parameters like consumer and access token etc.

check these links:

https://apigee.com/console/linkedin

Have you seen this: http://www.whitneyland.com/2011/03/iphone-oauth.html

or this:

https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

Comment: I am having problem in call back, So now i am searching for library which uses oAuth 2.0 as it does call back automatically if u dont specify. Do you happen to know any linkedin library which uses version 2.0 ?